# Wordpress blog view, different in mobile device than normal Desktop devices

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on Wordpress theme and after deploying on the server, blog seeming different in mobile devices.

For example you can open this link in desktop device and mobile device.
[Blog URL](http://blog.hubilo.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with jetpack plugin. Jetpack plugin has option of mobile responsive device, which was enabled.

For more Reference we can view below blog.

[Reference blog](https://wpgarage.com/tips/turn-mobile-view-remove-proudly-powered-wordpress-hint-jetpack/)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to responsive html. See closely in your blog's html source code and you will find `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`. That's why it's showing different in mobile and desktop. Though, to make responsive website, it's good and now-a-days it's the standard.

Comment: Thanks for your response. there is a plugin problem :) :).